# add class using jquery to a table row created using ajax

Tags: jquery

I have dynamically created a table using ajax (jQuery and PHP).  Once the ajax has been called and the table returned, I need to be able to access a table row using jQuery once the table has been loaded in it's holding DIV.

I just can't work out the jquery needed to access the table.

How do I access elements in this case in a table that have been created dynamically - I know that its something to do with them not bene in the dom at page load but I cant work out either the jquery to try and find for example a table row inside the dynamic table in the holding div (the holding DIV is part of the page when it loads and is not dynamic).

Comment: Access them to do what? Add event listeners? Other?

Comment: For example, once the table has loaded, the code behind the ajax that creates the dynamic table gives each dynamic TR an id based on a database id - e.g. id="tr_18" - I want to addClass for example to a certain row, but $("#tr_18").addClass("myclass"); is not working as it cant find the element - how do I find the dynamic tr_18 element with jquery on the dynamic table?

Comment: Also, the dynamic table is loaded into a holding DIV that is part of the php page on page load - eg <div id="mydiv">.  And then the data returned from the ajax does a $("#mydiv").html(data) - where data is the html returned from the ajax - in this case the dynamic table html

Comment: You shouldn't have any problem looking for an id ***after*** you insert that element. Provide a [mcve]. Can even add it to the response before you insert it if needed

Comment: try to use `$("#tr_18").addClass("myclass");` inside `.done()` .. `$.ajax({// your code}).done(function(){ $("#tr_18").addClass("myclass");  })`

Comment: Mohamed Yousefs solution worked.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what type of Ajax call are you using, but here is an example to do the work in jquery

```
$.get('/some-url/', function(data)
{
    var $data = $(data);
    $data.find('#someDiv').append('<p>Some Text</p>'); 
    $('body').append($data);          
 });
```